# Camel - how to add request parameter(throwExceptionOnFailure) to url?

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

I hav following route:

```
from("quartz2:findAll//myGroup/myTimerName?cron=" + pushProperties.getQuartz())
                //.setBody().constant("{ \"id\": \"FBJDBFJHSDBFJSBDfi\" }")
                .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=" + mongoDataConfiguration.getDatabase()
                        + "&operation=findAll&collection=" + mongoDataConfiguration.getDataPointCollection())
                .process(exchange -> {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(exchange.getIn().getBody()));
                }).streamCaching()
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(pushProperties.getHttpMethod()))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))                    
                .to(pushProperties.getUrl() + "&throwExceptionOnFailure=false").streamCaching()
```

As you can see I use `throwExceptionOnFailure=false`

and I take my url from configuration. But we found out that it works if

`pushProperties.getUrl()` = `localhost:8080/url?action=myaction`

and doesn't work in case of

`pushProperties.getUrl()` = `localhost:8080/url`

Is there universla way in camel to add request parameter to URL?

something like:

```
private String buildUrl() {
    String url = pushProperties.getUrl();
    return url + (url.contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "throwExceptionOnFailure=false";
}
```

inside Camel api

Answer (score 1):

That is because in case of `localhost:8080/url`, after appending it becomes like this

`localhost:8080/url&throwExceptionOnFailure=false`
which is wrong
It should be
`localhost:8080/url?throwExceptionOnFailure=false`,
In the first case it works you already have a requestpatam(`?action=myaction`) so the next one can be added with ampersand(&)

Comment: it is clear for me. I want to have method like  **addParamater("throwExceptionOnFailure", false)** I think it can be somewhere in camel api. Sure I can write my own but I want to use buit-in if it exists

Comment: according to the documentation http://camel.apache.org/servlet, you can set it as a header with key as `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY`

Comment: could not find *Exchange.HTTP_QUERY* in your link

Comment: at least                **.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("throwExceptionOnFailure=false"))** doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add your own logic to compose the endpoint to the `http` component at the runtime. This is because the `CamelContext` will process it during the route itself. The parameter `throwExceptionOnFailure` is a property from the `http` component.

I don't think that adding the parameter via `.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("throwExceptionOnFailure=false"))` shoud work because these parameters will be evaluated after the `http` component get processed, e.g. into the URL destination. Please, take a look at ["How to use a dynamic URI in to()"](https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html):

```
.toD(pushProperties.getUrl() + "&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

You could use the [simple expression](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/languages/simple-language.html) to write a logic to do what you want based on the result of `pushProperties.getUrl()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like how Camel configure HTTP component in this case, but this is what  it is.

What I suggest is to create a map of config, and append your args to it, and do a manual join with "&", then append it to the main url.

I do it like:

```java
public class MyProcessor {
    /**
     * Part of Camel HTTP component config are done with URL query parameters.
     */
    private static final Map<String, String> COMMON_QUERY_PARAMS = Map.of(
            // do not throw HttpOperationFailedException; we handle them ourselves
            "throwExceptionOnFailure", "false"
    );

    @Handler
    void configure(Exchange exchange, ...) {
        ...
        Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
        queryParams.put("foo", "bar");
        message.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, mergeAndJoin(queryParams));
        ...
    }
    
    private String mergeAndJoin(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
        // make sure HTTP config params put after event params
        return Stream.concat(queryParams.entrySet().stream(), COMMON_QUERY_PARAMS.entrySet().stream())
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
    }

}
```

Note that toD needs optimization but in that case, HTTP_QUERY cannot be used.

> When the optimised component is in use, then you cannot use the headers Exchange.HTTP_PATH and Exchange.HTTP_QUERY to provide dynamic values to override the uri in toD. If you want to use these headers, then use the plain to DSL instead. In other words these headers are used internally by toD to carry the dynamic details of the endpoint.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/toD-eip.html